# Google Chart API - internet connection requirement?

Tags: google-visualization, internet-connection

Does Google Chart API need internet connection on both server and client side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It's a web service.

Comment: Well it is not 100% true. There is an implementation of Google Chart API available as a standalone WAR. http://www.jfree.org/eastwood/

Comment: @banterCZ: It's still a web service.

Comment: Yes it is, but it can be installed on localhost.