# Vaadin Widgetset does not display on all networks

Tags: javascript, vaadin

I am experiencing something very tricky. I have two networks, one has internet access and other doesn't. When I load my vaadin web application project on these networks, it works well on the one with internet access and does not load the widget in the second network. Firebug reports:

```
<div class="pie chart"></div>.
```

I cant figure out what is going wrong. Is there a possibility that the widgetset is picking something from the internet on i ts own to display the pie chart? Or has it got something to do with the network security?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vaadin Widgetsets in general do not have requirement for a internet connection, and they should work in closed intranets as well, but some add-on widgets may have special limitations.

Sounds like you are using the 'Visualizations for Vaadin' add-on which is based on Google Chart API. And that indeed requires the internet connection.

See also: [Google Chart API - internet connection requirement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3316445/google-chart-api-internet-connection-requirement)